# java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for cucumber-core-7.3.4.jar

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-junit

I initially created a plain Java project that followed the steps mentioned [here](https://www.guru99.com/using-cucumber-selenium.html) and [here](https://www.edureka.co/blog/cucumber-selenium-tutorial/) but unfortunately, my project didn't work, I am getting this above error. I have not reached the step where it talks about integrating selenium.

Just to mention I used all the latest versions of the jar files as shown below.

[image]

I also got other various problems also, and to resolve them when I searched on the internet everyone was talking about the configuration inside the pom.xml file. But this file comes in the Maven project! so I converted my project to a Maven project. But that too didn't resolve my issues so I "disabled the Maven nature". No luck even after that.
currently, it is a Maven project but when I am following [this](https://www.guru99.com/images/2-2017/092917_0716_UsingCucumb15.png) step it is giving me the subject error.

This is how my package explorer look like:-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to start small with something working. And then after each change check if it still works. This will help you build an understanding of what each component and change does without overwhelming you.

Unfortunately you are following tutorials that do a whole lot at once. Try to break this down a bit. First learn about Maven, with plain Java and maybe a unit test. Then learn about how Eclipse works with Maven projects. Then use Cucumber with Maven, then add Selenium.

This may seem like a lot more work but it is faster because you'll only have to solve one problem at a time.

I don't have any tutorials for Maven or Eclipse but for Cucumber you use:

https://docs.cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/